# Capture all changing data from a cell to another using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My workbook's sheet1 A1 cell keeps updating with new data and my requirement is captured all that changes and save it to sheet2 "B" column.(new data will get added to a new row like B1,B2,B3 etc) 
Using below code I am able to achieve it using worksheet change function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        Dim intLastRow As Long
        intLastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheet2.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "B") = Target.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly if I enter data manually to my original cell ( sheet1 A1). But if I use any formula say "=C2", it's not working. Any data which is getting updated using formula is not getting captured on sheet2 B. Would like to know Is there anyway I can capture the values getting updated using formula too

Comment: Use the `worksheet_calculate` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

With Sheet2
    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        If .Value <> Sheet1.Range("A1").Value Then
            .Offset(1).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to save the data on a different workbook, can I use then like below. I am adding this code on the target excel. If .Value <> Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value Then
            .Offset(1).Value = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        End If

Comment: why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: I have already tried , but its not pulling data. looking for the syntax